# How to memoize hash across requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, memoization

In my Rails application I have a very *expensive* function that fetches a bunch of conversion rates from an external service once per day:

```
require 'open-uri'

module Currency

  def self.all
    @all ||= fetch_all
  end

  def self.get_rate(from_curr = "EUR", to_curr = "USD")
    all[from_curr][to_curr]
  end

  private

    def self.fetch_all
      hashes = {}
      CURRENCIES.keys.each do |currency|
        hash = JSON.parse(open(URI("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=#{currency}")).read)
        hashes[currency] = hash["rates"]
      end
      hashes
    end

end
```

Is there a way to *store* the result of this function (a hash) to speed things up? Right now, I am trying to store it in an instance variable `@all`, which speeds it up a little, however it is not persisted across requests. How can I keep it across requests?

Comment: Do you use any caching server?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Why don't you store the exchange rates in your database?

Comment: @spickermann: That's also an option. But what might be the advantage of that?

Comment: @Tintin81 Having a log of historical exchange rates in the database would be the biggest advantage IMO.

Comment: Conceptually a constant is not the best place to store the values, if it changes often is no longer a constant. I would agree with  spickermann and saving it to the database would be the best option.

Comment: OK, but isn't the database terribly slow? In my app I am doing a lot of currency conversion in many different places and I only need today's rates. Exchange rates from yesterday and earlier are nice to have in general, but useless in this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a file lets say `currency_rates.rb` in your initializer with the following code:

```
require 'open-uri'
hashes = {}
CURRENCIES.keys.each do |currency|
  hashes[currency] = JSON.parse(open(URI("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=#{currency}")).read)["rates"]
end
CURRENCY_RATES = hashes
```

Then write the following rake task which will run daily:

```
task update_currency_rates: :environment do
  require 'open-uri'
  hashes = {}
  CURRENCIES.keys.each do |currency|
    hashes[currency] = JSON.parse(open(URI("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=#{currency}")).read)["rates"]
  end
  Constant.const_set('CURRENCY_RATES', hashes)
end
```

The only drawback is that it will run every time you deploy new version of your app/on restart. You can go with it if you are ok with it.

You can avoid that if you use caching like `memcachier` or something, then you can do like,

```
def currency_rates
  Rails.cache.fetch('currency_rates', expires_in: 24.hours) do
    # write above code in some method and call here which will return hash and thus it will be cached.
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But what do I need the initializer for when the rake task is already fetching the rates from the remote service? Is the code duplication really necessary?

Comment: rake task is for updating the values daily. Suppose you don't initialize them on app start, your code will break as the rates will be absent. Even if you run the task moment after the deployment, it will take not less than a minute to populate values. If you are ignorant about the precise/exact rates for that much time, you can set default (hardcoded) rates for each country during initialisation and then run task to update them. It depends on how critical the usecase is.

Comment: Regarding code duplication, please don't do it. Create a class method and call it from initializer and task both. That's for understanding..

Comment: The rake task does not do any good. You'r app and the rake task run in 2 different process. A constant set within your rake task is not set within your rails app. `Rails.cache.fetch` is a good hint. When you use memcache then it works with multiple servers and multiple unicorn processes too.

Comment: @slowjack2k ohh yes...that's a good catch..didn't think of it. And yes, caching is anyday better. I wonder what could be other solution to update the data without caching?

Answer (score 1):

I would initilize the hash lazy like this:

```
 require 'open-uri'
 require 'json'

 module Currency

   def self.get_rate(from_curr = "EUR", to_curr = "USD")
     @memorized_result ||={}
     @memorized_result.fetch(from_curr) do |not_found_key|
       data = JSON.parse(open(URI("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=# {not_found_key}")).read)
       @memorized_result[not_found_key] = data["rates"]
     end[to_curr]
   end
 end
```

I think you don't need all the exchange rates at all the time. So you can speed up things by fetching only the required one at a time. Over the time you keep all rates in memory.

This is persisted between requests in some edge cases. It depends on your server, for instance, unicorn uses multiple processes. Every process has it's own
`@memorized_result` variable, which needs to be filled.

If you want to share this data betweend multiple processes or servers then you need a storage for the fetched data which can be shared between multiple processes.

If you need a time to life for your entries then I would tweak @Md. Farhan Memon Rails cache hint like this:

```
def get_rate(from_curr = "EUR", to_curr = "USD")
   Rails.cache.fetch("currency_rates_#{from_curr}_#{to_curr}", expires_in: 24.hours) do
      data = JSON.parse(open(URI("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=#{from_curr}")).read)
      data["rates"][to_curr]
  end
end
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar, using `Rails.cache`. Thanks for your input.